# Does '...time zone of in the morning' make sense?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> I waited for my favorite **time zone of in the morning.**

Does the sentence above make sense? I mean that time zone is 'the range of time' in this sentence.

Comment: Are you using "time zone" in the [usual sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)?

Comment: I mean that time zone is 'the range of time' in this sentence.

Comment: Ah, that's not a time zone, then. A *time zone* relates to things like [KST](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/kst). You might be trying to say you waited for your favourite time "of the evening" - the special time that you like very much, which takes place during *part* of the evening. Or are you saying that the *whole* evening is your favourite period of the day?

Answer (score 2):

You mean to say **time of day** or **time of the day**.

> The evening is my favorite time of (the) day.
>
> Early morning is my favorite time of (the) day.

Answer (score 0):

No, a time zone is a place in the world where people set their clocks in a particular way, e.g. China Time Zone, Eastern Time Zone or Europe/London.